# Narrowing Implicit Casting from Short/Byte

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

According to the Java Language Specification:

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte
>   - Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short.
>   - Character and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type char.

This makes sense to me that there is implicit casting for integer literals and integer constant expressions to short, byte, and char types assuming it is in range of the target type.

So does this mean that narrowing implicit casting is irrelevant when going from type short and byte (for example short to byte, short to char, byte to char) because from what I understand, there are no such short/byte literals or constant expressions?

Comment: Probably, though it’s always possible that there will be short and byte constants in a future version of the Java language.  (Note that short-to-char and byte-to-char are not narrowing conversions;  the only type smaller than short is byte, and there are no types smaller than byte.)

Comment: I looked into and according to the jls https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3
short to char and short to byte are narrowing, byte to char is a widening and narrowing